# Is there way to HeroAnimate the value of TextField in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

thank you for reading.
I want to know the way to HeroAnimate the value of TextField in Flutter.

I tried wrapping TextField with Hero(), but it won't work and shows this error code.
"TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor."

So, my goal will be HeroAnimating the letter in the TextField to the Text of Next View.

Hoping for a solution

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Error states that **TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor.** Simply **wrapping** your whole Widget into `Scaffold` will solve the problem.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Material(
    child: YourAwesomeWidget(),
}
```

Comment: Actually this textField is already rapped with Scaffold.
I think the error meant it needs a direct Material widget ancestor.

Comment: @naokiperez add your code so thing get more clear and also error log